# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 using Maven for wikixmlj

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to install wikixmlj on the master node of a Spark cluster I started on EC2 using the Spark-EC2 install script.

I ran the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/synhershko/wikixmlj.git
cd wikixmlj
mvn package install
```

Turns out I didn't have Maven installed, so I ran this:

```
sudo wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
mvn --version
```

Then, I went back to the beginning and ran `mvn package install`

I got these errors:

```
testSaxParser(edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.WikiXMLParserTest): org/apache/tools/bzip2/CBZip2InputStream : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
testGetSAXParserFromRelativeFileName(edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.WikiXMLParserFactoryTest): org/apache/tools/bzip2/CBZip2InputStream : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
testGetSAXParserFromAbsoluteFileName(edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.WikiXMLParserFactoryTest): org/apache/tools/bzip2/CBZip2InputStream : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I have little experience with Java or Maven -- I'm just following the SparkBench install guide. Does anybody have any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using Java 7? This unsupported major.minor version 52.0 is in my opinion releated to the uses Java version. Looks like you require at least Java 8.

Comment: [Maven (3.3.9)](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) needs at least JDK 7 but the code look like needed JDK 8